# Getting the token tree to appear contextually

Tags: hooks, tokens

I'm writing my own file formatter which is supposed to be Token-compatible. As it will be also used on taxonomy term pages, it should accept taxonomy term token. What am I doing wrong in `hook_field_formatter_settings_form` by saying:

```
'#token_types' => array('node', 'taxonomy_term')
```

so that I don't get term-related tokens at all? Cleared cache many a time.
Preferably, I would like the tokens to appear contextually: taxonomy term - when managing display of taxonomy term page, node - when managing display of a node page. Can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The surpising answer was:
`'#token_types' => array('node', 'term')`
Thanks to davereid!